# Can't get jQuery stop conflicting

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

Before going to the detail, I'd like to say that I did a lot of searching and tried noConflict() but no luck. Please correct me if I used it not correctly, don't just give me the link to any answered question which suggest the OP to use noConflict().

I have a html form which use two jQuery function, one for styling tooltips, one for uploading file (both of them are downloaded from the internet, I have no idea how to use jQuery). Both of them work perfectly, as long as the other script not included. I'm finding a way to have both function working together.

This is my HTML code: (or check this link: http://yurivn.net/imageuploader/index1.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org

/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Google Picasa Image Uploader</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yurivn.net/imageuploader/style.css" type="text/css" />
<!-- tooltips styling script --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yurivn.net/imageuploader/tooltip.css"/>
<script src="http://yurivn.net/imageuploader/tooltip1.js"></script>
<script src="http://yurivn.net/imageuploader/tooltip2.js"></script>
<!-- upload script --> 
<script  type="text/ecmascript" src="http://yurivn.net/imageuploader/jquery.js?v=3.1"></script>
<script  type="text/ecmascript" src="http://yurivn.net/imageuploader/script_embed.js?v=3.1"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$( document ).tooltip();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="embed" style="display: inline-block;"></div><div id="status" style="display: inline-block;"></div>
<div id="result" style="display:none"></div>
<div><textarea class="primary textbox" id="links" name="onlinelink" readonly></textarea></div>
<input type="text" title="this tooltip should be styled"/>
</body>
</html>
```

The upload script worked, but tooltip not worked, and vice versa after adding noConflict() like this:

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
$(function() {
$( document ).tooltip();
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

What am I missing?

P/s: I used absolute URL for those included script instead of pasting them here, which will make my question become too long. If you want to check those script, please check these URL out, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some situations I have encountered some conflicts such like yours but often found that putting jQuery functions in the end of document right before `</body>` to be the best practice instead of putting it inside `<head>`.  But the correct formating of code that was suggested by @RobH is the correct snippet.

See working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/farondomenic/ku7m7/1/

Answer (score 3):

You're using it wrong :)

```
<script>

    jQuery.noConflict();
    // $ no longer references jQuery.

    (function($) {
        // use $ in here:
        $(function () {
            $(document).tooltip();
        });
    }(jQuery));

</script>
```

Comment: @Mee, actually no because once jQuery functions are nested inside $function(), then anything is possible with extra focus on identifying right elements with id or class for jQuery functions to be implemented/executed.

Comment: @Faron I don't think so. Please check this: http://jsfiddle.net/ku7m7/ tooltip function worked, but if I used RobH's code, none of them work.

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle to edited verison and I am getting the working result as shown at http://jsfiddle.net/farondomenic/ku7m7/1/ 

In some situations I have encountered some conflicts such like yours but often found that putting jQuery functions in the end of document right before `</body>` to be the best practice instead of putting it inside `<head>`.

Comment: Wow it worked, like a charm. But I can't see the code, what did you do? That's what I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/ku7m7/2/

Comment: nvm, I got it worked. Thank you my hero, please make this an answer